# A word to describe something that has a clear-cut purpose and consequently works out of the box

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word that would convey the idea of something that adresses a definite problem set and consequently lets you do so without much effort.

Here's an example:

- Hammers are designed to drive nails
- Hammers are consequently very easy to use to achieve that exact purpose
- (And not very good at doing something else)

---

A small twist: I'm looking for words that emphasize the "designed to" aspect.

For example, `appropriate` wouldn't be entirely - well - appropriate because it conveys the idea that the tool happens to fit the bill, not that it was designed with the purpose of doing so.

Comment: The Space Shuttle is designed for the express purpose of going up into orbit and is good for very little else, but I wouldn't say it is easy to achieve even in the Space Shuttle.

Comment: Would you settle for a hyphenated word?  *purpose-built*

Comment: @Jim Indeed, the word I'm looking for - if it exists - wouldn't be appropriate to describe the space shuttle.

Comment: @Jim Thanks for your suggestion! I would, and purpose-built is an interesting choice. However, I think I'm looking for a word that would suggest the ease-of-use aspect. (Purpose built would be great for the space shuttle! ;) )

Comment: I guess my point is that just because something is built for a clear-cut purpose doesn't necessarily mean that it works "out of the box."

Comment: So you want a word that means *designed for ease of use*?  along the lines of *ergonomic*?  But my guess is that's not the word you want.

Comment: @Jim Yes; I'm looking for a word that would apply to those cases where ease of use is achieved by removing extra cruft - which in turn means the tool is only fit for its specific purpose.

Comment: @Jim Yes, I think ergonomic is close to what I'm looking for! Now that you mention it, my "specification" sounds too limited - I think I'm trying to find a word that also suggests efficiency and focus on the task / purpose!

Comment: How about *optimized*?

Comment: @Jim That's a great word!

Comment: I use my hammer for everything! From typing up comments in stackexchange to picking out navel lint. Concordingly I find your preposition false! :p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Optimized***, from

> [**optimal**](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/optimal) : The best, most favourable or desirable, especially under some restriction.

Comment: Where is the "out-of-the-box" meaning of optimal?

Comment: @Jim- You need to read through the whole comment string.  I think the answer OP was looking for was not quite captured by the question as worded.

Answer (score 1):

**Ready-To-Use** in general can be found by Googling. The object type might imply the purpose or use that it's ready for. (Obviously a ready-to-use lawnmower wouldn't be used for cooking.)

But for a specific purpose, that purpose can be include. The most common that I'm aware of are

- **ready-to-wear**, for clothing
- **ready-to-fly**, model airplanes and rockets
- **ready-to-eat**, self explanatory

I thought this one was funny, because it's really not ready at all: "ready-to-assemble" :-)